# Error: Maximum function nesting level of '512' reached when injecting custom service to webform (6.x) handler

Tags: webforms

I'm trying to use my custom service in the handler like this (in webform 6.0-beta1):

```php
class TriggerAutomationWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {

  /**
   * Ecomail.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\ecomail_automation\EcomailInterface
   */
  protected $ecomail;

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    $instance = parent::create($container, $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $instance->ecomail = $container->get('ecomail_automation.ecomail');
  }
?>
```

`mymodule.services.yml` file looks like this:

```
services:
  ecomail_automation.ecomail:
    class: Drupal\ecomail_automation\Ecomail
    arguments: [ '@config.factory', '@logger.factory' ]
```

My `Drupal\ecomail_automation\Ecomail` class in constructed like this (`\Ecomail` class is different class in a global namespace - see https://packagist.org/packages/ecomailcz/ecomail):

```php
  public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $config, LoggerChannelFactoryInterface $logger_factory) {
    $this->config = $config->get('ecomail_webform.settings');
    $this->logger = $logger_factory;
    $this->ecomail = new \Ecomail($this->config->get('api_key'));
  }
?>
```

This leads to error (shortened to important parts):

```
Error: Maximum function nesting level of '512' reached, aborting! in Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginBase->__construct() (line 53 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/PluginBase.php).

Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginBase->__construct(Array, 'trigger_automation', Array) (Line: 141)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase::create(Object, Array, 'trigger_automation', Array) (Line: 43)
Drupal\ecomail_automation\Plugin\WebformHandler\TriggerAutomationWebformHandler::create(Object, Array, 'trigger_automation', Array) (Line: 21)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\Factory\ContainerFactory->createInstance('trigger_automation', Array) (Line: 76)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginManagerBase->createInstance('trigger_automation', Array) (Line: 81)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultLazyPluginCollection->initializePlugin('trigger_automation') (Line: 35)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerPluginCollection->initializePlugin('trigger_automation') (Line: 80)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\LazyPluginCollection->get('trigger_automation') (Line: 40)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerPluginCollection->initializePlugin('trigger_automation') (Line: 80)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\LazyPluginCollection->get('trigger_automation') (Line: 40)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerPluginCollection->initializePlugin('trigger_automation') (Line: 80)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\LazyPluginCollection->get('trigger_automation') (Line: 40)
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to return something from the `create` static function or is that just a typo in a question

Comment: You're right. Stupid me...

Comment: It was my typo. Sorry for taking your time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're instanciating the `Ecomail` object into your Ecomail constructor `$this->ecomail = new \Ecomail($this->config->get('api_key'));` which is kind of a fork bomb.

Your Ecomail is creating an Ecomail itself creating another Ecomail, etc.
That's an infinite loop

Comment: Yes, that's what I assumed. How would you solve it?

Comment: I tried to fix it using `if (($this->ecomail instanceof \Ecomail) != TRUE) {
      $this->ecomail = new \Ecomail($this->config->get('api_key'));
    }` but it didn't help

Comment: Why does your service need an instance of itself which is generated when it's generated? That will never be resolvable, it's your classic infinite loop

Comment: @Clive Sorry for misunderstanding - it's a different class in a global namespace. I edited my question, hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: In fact, I originally copied the solution from https://www.drupal.org/project/ecomail_webform contrib module - things broke, because of changes caused by https://www.drupal.org/node/3076421